# How to Route U-Phoria UMC 204HD Audio Interface?

Tags: audio, routes

*So* I have the U-Phoria UMC 204HD Audio Interface.
What I need is the Monitoring (What I hear with zero Latency or The audio sent to the Interface) to be captured by another program(preferably, VoiceMeeter) with what ever means. If this is not possible... I need something similar.
*In other words* I need the monitoring audio to be heard with zero latency(or at least less than 10ms), but my stream to have the same audio regardless if it is zero latency.
I have Fruity Loops Producer Edition and Voicemeeter. I feel these Options *should* be efficient.
However I have spent days modifying settings to try and make something work, to no avail.
I am capturing Rocksmith 2014 Remastered Edition with the Audio Interface Driver. Which seems to only work with in this way. Any other ASIO driver doesnt work Ive tried them all. And ive tried so many different settings, It simply is not the way to go.
Any help is appreciated. I would likely try anything. Thank you.

I have tried Asio4all. No result.
I have tried routing with multiple instances of FL Studio with no results.
I have tried routing with the Audio interface itself. With no results.

I have tried Reaper with ReaRoute with only a "puking" sound in the very beginning of Rocksmith starting. Regardless of the buffering and sample settings I have tried. Believe me i tried both for 9 hours straight. ReaRoute isnt going to work.

Comment: Hi, your question is off-topic here... Maybe you can ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com). Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)